# Why won't Silverlight sounds play on some computers?

Tags: silverlight, audio

My Silverlight app successfully plays a repeating alert sound every ten seconds on a number of my own computers. One of my clients hears no sounds. I was just on the phone with him and verified that he could hear basic Windows sounds, sounds from another application, and sounds from another web page (not Silverlight, however) within IE.

Does anyone know of any settings which might affect Silverlight's ability to play sounds on a system which otherwise sounds (ha, ha) fine?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he has a problem with his DirectX (or more specifically DirectSound) installation.